# Is 3.5.2 backward compatible with 2

Tags: typescript

I have a Node project created some time ago, and it was using version 2 of Typescript.

I have since moved the project to a new computer. I installed the latest Typescript, ie 3.5.2.

When I run things like `npm audit fix`, I get warnings such as:

> npm WARN tslint@5.9.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Is it ok to ignore the warning?

Comment: Upgrade tslint and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript releases breaking changes between versions on [their Github wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes). Regarding whether or not you can ignore the warning is entirely up to your code-base.